# DB2 tables replication into Hadoop dsv, .dat or .txt format through IIDR CDC

Tags: hadoop, db2, cdc

I have successfully replicated the DB2 table into Hadoop IIDR CDC. However, The files are in a csv format and the Hadoop customer is asking to that the tandard delimiters is \x1c, and the files that they typically accept are in a .dsv or .dat format, though also accommodate .txt.
I have tried to create flat file, but it did not ask for Kerberos setting and replication failed (authentication fail). I got this error message
An exception occurred in DataStage target.
Error opening flat file.
Error: /TST/DL/CARD/HADOOPTABLE.@2020173.T210420110 (No such file or directory)

Please let me know how to setup the configure for dsv, ,dat or .txt formate?

Comment: Did I get you right, that you were able to make CDC for DS produce files in a local file system, but you have problems with a DataStage job using the File Connector stage?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP is using IBM Data Replication CDC directly targeting Hadoop via WebHDFS API as per :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/concepts/map_to_hadoop.html

In this case, CDC formats the files uploaded via WebHDFS as CSV with standard comma field delimiter.

To modify formats, typically the formatter user exit could be implemented to a flat file target.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/infosphere-change-data-capture-how-can-you-change-field-delimiter-flat-file-datastage

I am not aware if the Hadoop WebHDFS target for CDC supports this user exit formatter tho...